# Using Gradle on Windows 10 for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to setup Gradle on Windows 10 so I could use in my Android Studio. I am trying to run the command `./gradlew clean build` But getting this below:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

**What I have done.**

I have downloaded and Extracted the downloaded zip file named gradle-3.3-all.zip and placed it in `C:\gradle\bin`  I have also set my Environment Variables to `GRADLE_HOME = C:\gradle` and `Path to C:\gradle\bin`

I then restarted my Android Studio, It still doesn't work.

Please any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Android Studio comes with Gradle... Also the whole purpose of the `gradlew` is so you don't **need** to download Gradle... Your error is that you don't have Java setup properly

Comment: Ok thanks, So how do I make sure that my Java is setup properly?

Comment: Well, its a requirement of Android Studio, so as long as that runs, I would think it is okay

Comment: If `gradle` is on your PATH, use `gradle clean build` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and getting "'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Comment: Then, you've not set `%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` in your PATH correctly, or haven't restarted the CMD

Answer (score 0):

just install JDK form oracle's website then install android studio,it will work , after installing java ,add JAVA_HOME to your environment path